# Error in Kafka and Zookeeper container made by a docker-compose file

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, docker-compose, apache-zookeeper

I need to expose JMX ports of Kafka and Zookeeper container to connect a monitoring tool such as Lenses or Grafana. The monitoring tool would be installed on a different server.

I made a docker-compose file to apply the container's configurations but it throws some error.

Here is the Docker-compose YAML file.

Any help is appreciated.

```
version: '3.2'

services:
  zookeeper:
    container_name: zookeeper
    image: wurstmeister/zookeeper:latest
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181


      KAFKA_JMX_OPTS: >-
        -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote=true 
        -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false   
        -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false 
        -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=156.17.42.120 
        -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=11992
        -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.rmi.port=11992


      JMX_PORT: 11992
    ports:
    - "2181:2181"
    - "11992:11992"



  # https://hub.docker.com/r/confluentinc/cp-kafka/
  kafka:
    container_name: kafka
    image: wurstmeister/kafka:latest
    environment:
      ## the >- used below infers a value which is a string and properly 
      ## ignore the multiple lines resulting in one long string: 
      ## https://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html
      KAFKA_LOG_RETENTION_MS: 10000
      KAFKA_LOG_RETENTION_CHECK_INTERVAL_MS: 5000
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: >- 
        LISTENER_DOCKER_INTERNAL://kafka:19092, 
        LISTENER_DOCKER_EXTERNAL://156.17.42.120:9092
      JMX_PORT: 11991
      KAFKA_JMX_OPTS:   >-
                -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=156.17.42.120
                -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=11991
                -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.rmi.port=11991
                -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote=true
                -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
                -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false

      KAFKA_LISTENERS: >-
        LISTENER_DOCKER_INTERNAL://kafka:19091,
        LISTENER_DOCKER_EXTERNAL://156.17.42.120:9092



      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: >- 
        LISTENER_DOCKER_INTERNAL:PLAINTEXT,
        LISTENER_DOCKER_EXTERNAL:PLAINTEXT

      KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: LISTENER_DOCKER_INTERNAL
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_LOG4J_LOGGERS: >- 
        kafka.controller=INFO,
        kafka.producer.async.DefaultEventHandler=INFO,
        state.change.logger=INFO

    ports:
    - 9092:9092
    - 11991:11991

    depends_on:
    - zookeeper
    volumes:
    - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
```

Docker-compose Log;

```
[33mzookeeper    |[0m Using config: /opt/zookeeper-3.4.13/bin/../conf/zoo.cfg
[36mkafka        |[0m   delete.topic.enable = true
[33mzookeeper    |[0m 2020-02-04 12:03:59,394 [myid:] - INFO  [main:QuorumPeerConfig@136] - Reading configuration from: /opt/zookeeper-3.4.13/bin/../conf/zoo.cfg
[36mkafka        |[0m   fetch.purgatory.purge.interval.requests = 1000
[33mzookeeper    |[0m 2020-02-04 12:03:59,398 [myid:] - INFO  [main:DatadirCleanupManager@78] - autopurge.snapRetainCount set to 3
[36mkafka        |[0m   group.initial.rebalance.delay.ms = 0
[33mzookeeper    |[0m 2020-02-04 12:03:59,398 [myid:] - INFO  [main:DatadirCleanupManager@79] - autopurge.purgeInterval set to 1
[36mkafka        |[0m   group.max.session.timeout.ms = 1800000
[33mzookeeper    |[0m 2020-02-04 12:03:59,399 [myid:] - WARN  [main:QuorumPeerMain@116] - Either no config or no quorum defined in config, running  in standalone mode
[36mkafka        |[0m   group.max.size = 2147483647
[33mzookeeper    |[0m 2020-02-04 12:03:59,399 [myid:] - INFO  [PurgeTask:DatadirCleanupManager$PurgeTask@138] - Purge task started.
[36mkafka        |[0m   group.min.session.timeout.ms = 6000
[33mzookeeper    |[0m 2020-02-04 12:03:59,406 [myid:] - INFO  [PurgeTask:DatadirCleanupManager$PurgeTask@144] - Purge task completed.
[36mkafka        |[0m   host.name = 
[33mzookeeper    |[0m 2020-02-04 12:03:59,408 [myid:] - INFO  [main:QuorumPeerConfig@136] - Reading configuration from: /opt/zookeeper-3.4.13/bin/../conf/zoo.cfg
[36mkafka        |[0m   inter.broker.listener.name = LISTENER_DOCKER_INTERNAL
[33mzookeeper    |[0m 2020-02-04 12:03:59,409 [myid:] - INFO  [main:ZooKeeperServerMain@98] - Starting server
[36mkafka        |[0m   inter.broker.protocol.version = 2.4-IV1
[33mzookeeper    |[0m 2020-02-04 12:03:59,414 [myid:] - INFO  [main:Environment@100] - Server environment:zookeeper.version=3.4.13-2d71af4dbe22557fda74f9a9b4309b15a7487f03, built on 06/29/2018 04:05 GMT
[36mkafka        |[0m   kafka.metrics.polling.interval.secs = 10
[33mzookeeper    |[0m 2020-02-04 12:03:59,415 [myid:] - INFO  [main:Environment@100] - Server environment:host.name=185df4f257aa
[36mkafka        |[0m   kafka.metrics.reporters = []
[33mzookeeper    |[0m 2020-02-04 12:03:59,415 [myid:] - INFO  [main:Environment@100] - Server environment:java.version=1.7.0_65
[36mkafka        |[0m   leader.imbalance.check.interval.seconds = 300
[33mzookeeper    |[0m 2020-02-04 12:03:59,415 [myid:] - INFO  [main:Environment@100] - Server environment:java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
[36mkafka        |[0m   leader.imbalance.per.broker.percentage = 10
[33mzookeeper    |[0m 2020-02-04 12:03:59,415 [myid:] - INFO  [main:Environment@100] - Server environment:java.home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre
[36mkafka        |[0m   listener.security.protocol.map = LISTENER_DOCKER_INTERNAL:PLAINTEXT, LISTENER_DOCKER_EXTERNAL:PLAINTEXT
[33mzookeeper    |[0m 2020-02-04 12:03:59,415 [myid:] - INFO  [main:Environment@100] - Server environment:java.class.path=/opt/zookeeper-3.4.13/bin/../build/classes:/opt/zookeeper-3.4.13/bin/../build/lib/*.jar:/opt/zookeeper-3.4.13/bin/../lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.25.jar:/opt/zookeeper-3.4.13/bin/../lib/slf4j-api-1.7.25.jar:/opt/zookeeper-3.4.13/bin/../lib/netty-3.10.6.Final.jar:/opt/zookeeper-3.4.13/bin/../lib/log4j-1.2.17.jar:/opt/zookeeper-3.4.13/bin/../lib/jline-0.9.94.jar:/opt/zookeeper-3.4.13/bin/../lib/audience-annotations-0.5.0.jar:/opt/zookeeper-3.4.13/bin/../zookeeper-3.4.13.jar:/opt/zookeeper-3.4.13/bin/../src/java/lib/*.jar:/opt/zookeeper-3.4.13/bin/../conf:
[36mkafka        |[0m   listeners = LISTENER_DOCKER_INTERNAL://kafka:19091, LISTENER_DOCKER_EXTERNAL://156.17.42.120:9092
[33mzookeeper    |[0m 2020-02-04 12:03:59,415 [myid:] - INFO  [main:Environment@100] - Server environment:java.library.path=/usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/jni:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/usr/lib/jni:/lib:/usr/lib
[36mkafka        |[0m   log.cleaner.backoff.ms = 15000
[33mzookeeper    |[0m 2020-02-04 12:03:59,415 [myid:] - INFO  [main:Environment@100] - Server environment:java.io.tmpdir=/tmp
[36mkafka        |[0m   log.cleaner.dedupe.buffer.size = 134217728
[33mzookeeper    |[0m 2020-02-04 12:03:59,417 [myid:] - INFO  [main:Environment@100] - Server environment:java.compiler=<NA>
[36mkafka        |[0m   log.cleaner.delete.retention.ms = 86400000
[33mzookeeper    |[0m 2020-02-04 12:03:59,418 [myid:] - INFO  [main:Environment@100] - Server environment:os.name=Linux
[36mkafka        |[0m   log.cleaner.enable = true
[33mzookeeper    |[0m 2020-02-04 12:03:59,418 [myid:] - INFO  [main:Environment@100] - Server environment:os.arch=amd64
[36mkafka        |[0m   log.cleaner.io.buffer.load.factor = 0.9
[33mzookeeper    |[0m 2020-02-04 12:03:59,418 [myid:] - INFO  [main:Environment@100] - Server environment:os.version=4.18.0-147.3.1.el8_1.x86_64
[36mkafka        |[0m   log.cleaner.io.buffer.size = 524288
[33mzookeeper    |[0m 2020-02-04 12:03:59,418 [myid:] - INFO  [main:Environment@100] - Server environment:user.name=root
[36mkafka        |[0m   log.cleaner.io.max.bytes.per.second = 1.7976931348623157E308
[33mzookeeper    |[0m 2020-02-04 12:03:59,418 [myid:] - INFO  [main:Environment@100] - Server environment:user.home=/root
[36mkafka        |[0m   log.cleaner.max.compaction.lag.ms = 9223372036854775807
[33mzookeeper    |[0m 2020-02-04 12:03:59,418 [myid:] - INFO  [main:Environment@100] - Server environment:user.dir=/opt/zookeeper-3.4.13
[36mkafka        |[0m   log.cleaner.min.cleanable.ratio = 0.5
[33mzookeeper    |[0m 2020-02-04 12:03:59,421 [myid:] - INFO  [main:ZooKeeperServer@836] - tickTime set to 2000
[36mkafka        |[0m   log.cleaner.min.compaction.lag.ms = 0
[33mzookeeper    |[0m 2020-02-04 12:03:59,421 [myid:] - INFO  [main:ZooKeeperServer@845] - minSessionTimeout set to -1
[36mkafka        |[0m   log.cleaner.threads = 1
[33mzookeeper    |[0m 2020-02-04 12:03:59,422 [myid:] - INFO  [main:ZooKeeperServer@854] - maxSessionTimeout set to -1
[36mkafka        |[0m   log.cleanup.policy = [delete]
[33mzookeeper    |[0m 2020-02-04 12:03:59,430 [myid:] - INFO  [main:ServerCnxnFactory@117] - Using org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxnFactory as server connection factory
[36mkafka        |[0m   log.dir = /tmp/kafka-logs
[33mzookeeper    |[0m 2020-02-04 12:03:59,435 [myid:] - INFO  [main:NIOServerCnxnFactory@89] - binding to port 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181
[36mkafka        |[0m   log.dirs = /kafka/kafka-logs-acff9186a4ad
[33mzookeeper    |[0m 2020-02-04 12:04:02,603 [myid:] - INFO  [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181:NIOServerCnxnFactory@215] - Accepted socket connection from /172.18.0.3:43840
[36mkafka        |[0m   log.flush.interval.messages = 9223372036854775807
[33mzookeeper    |[0m 2020-02-04 12:04:02,608 [myid:] - INFO  [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181:ZooKeeperServer@949] - Client attempting to establish new session at /172.18.0.3:43840
[36mkafka        |[0m   log.flush.interval.ms = null
[33mzookeeper    |[0m 2020-02-04 12:04:02,610 [myid:] - INFO  [SyncThread:0:FileTxnLog@213] - Creating new log file: log.1
[36mkafka        |[0m   log.flush.offset.checkpoint.interval.ms = 60000
[33mzookeeper    |[0m 2020-02-04 12:04:02,661 [myid:] - INFO  [SyncThread:0:ZooKeeperServer@694] - Established session 0x1001e9c10d90000 with negotiated timeout 6000 for client /172.18.0.3:43840
[33mzookeeper    |[0m 2020-02-04 12:04:02,815 [myid:] - INFO  [ProcessThread(sid:0 cport:2181)::PrepRequestProcessor@653] - Got user-level KeeperException when processing sessionid:0x1001e9c10d90000 type:create cxid:0x2 zxid:0x3 txntype:-1 reqpath:n/a Error Path:/brokers Error:KeeperErrorCode = NoNode for /brokers
[36mkafka        |[0m   log.flush.scheduler.interval.ms = 9223372036854775807
[33mzookeeper    |[0m 2020-02-04 12:04:02,870 [myid:] - INFO  [ProcessThread(sid:0 cport:2181)::PrepRequestProcessor@653] - Got user-level KeeperException when processing sessionid:0x1001e9c10d90000 type:create cxid:0x6 zxid:0x7 txntype:-1 reqpath:n/a Error Path:/config Error:KeeperErrorCode = NoNode for /config
[36mkafka        |[0m   log.flush.start.offset.checkpoint.interval.ms = 60000
[33mzookeeper    |[0m 2020-02-04 12:04:02,908 [myid:] - INFO  [ProcessThread(sid:0 cport:2181)::PrepRequestProcessor@653] - Got user-level KeeperException when processing sessionid:0x1001e9c10d90000 type:create cxid:0x9 zxid:0xa txntype:-1 reqpath:n/a Error Path:/admin Error:KeeperErrorCode = NoNode for /admin
[36mkafka        |[0m   log.index.interval.bytes = 4096
[33mzookeeper    |[0m 2020-02-04 12:04:03,223 [myid:] - INFO  [ProcessThread(sid:0 cport:2181)::PrepRequestProcessor@653] - Got user-level KeeperException when processing sessionid:0x1001e9c10d90000 type:create cxid:0x15 zxid:0x15 txntype:-1 reqpath:n/a Error Path:/cluster Error:KeeperErrorCode = NoNode for /cluster
[36mkafka        |[0m   log.index.size.max.bytes = 10485760
[33mzookeeper    |[0m 2020-02-04 12:04:04,030 [myid:] - INFO  [ProcessThread(sid:0 cport:2181)::PrepRequestProcessor@487] - Processed session termination for sessionid: 0x1001e9c10d90000
[33mzookeeper    |[0m 2020-02-04 12:04:04,045 [myid:] - INFO  [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181:NIOServerCnxn@1056] - Closed socket connection for client /172.18.0.3:43840 which had sessionid 0x1001e9c10d90000
[36mkafka        |[0m   log.message.downconversion.enable = true
[33mzookeeper    |[0m 2020-02-04 13:03:59,399 [myid:] - INFO  [PurgeTask:DatadirCleanupManager$PurgeTask@138] - Purge task started.
[36mkafka        |[0m   log.message.format.version = 2.4-IV1
[33mzookeeper    |[0m 2020-02-04 13:03:59,400 [myid:] - INFO  [PurgeTask:DatadirCleanupManager$PurgeTask@144] - Purge task completed.
[36mkafka        |[0m   log.message.timestamp.difference.max.ms = 9223372036854775807
[36mkafka        |[0m   log.message.timestamp.type = CreateTime
[36mkafka        |[0m   log.preallocate = false
[36mkafka        |[0m   log.retention.bytes = -1
[36mkafka        |[0m   log.retention.check.interval.ms = 5000
[36mkafka        |[0m   log.retention.hours = 168
[36mkafka        |[0m   log.retention.minutes = null
[36mkafka        |[0m   log.retention.ms = 10000
[36mkafka        |[0m   log.roll.hours = 168
[36mkafka        |[0m   log.roll.jitter.hours = 0
[36mkafka        |[0m   log.roll.jitter.ms = null
[36mkafka        |[0m   log.roll.ms = null
[36mkafka        |[0m   log.segment.bytes = 1073741824
[36mkafka        |[0m   log.segment.delete.delay.ms = 60000
[36mkafka        |[0m   max.connections = 2147483647
[36mkafka        |[0m   max.connections.per.ip = 2147483647
[36mkafka        |[0m   max.connections.per.ip.overrides = 
[36mkafka        |[0m   max.incremental.fetch.session.cache.slots = 1000
[36mkafka        |[0m   message.max.bytes = 1000012
[36mkafka        |[0m   metric.reporters = []
[36mkafka        |[0m   metrics.num.samples = 2
[36mkafka        |[0m   metrics.recording.level = INFO
[36mkafka        |[0m   metrics.sample.window.ms = 30000
[36mkafka        |[0m   min.insync.replicas = 1
[36mkafka        |[0m   num.io.threads = 8
[36mkafka        |[0m   num.network.threads = 3
[36mkafka        |[0m   num.partitions = 1
[36mkafka        |[0m   num.recovery.threads.per.data.dir = 1
[36mkafka        |[0m   num.replica.alter.log.dirs.threads = null
[36mkafka        |[0m   num.replica.fetchers = 1
[36mkafka        |[0m   offset.metadata.max.bytes = 4096
[36mkafka        |[0m   offsets.commit.required.acks = -1
[36mkafka        |[0m   offsets.commit.timeout.ms = 5000
[36mkafka        |[0m   offsets.load.buffer.size = 5242880
[36mkafka        |[0m   offsets.retention.check.interval.ms = 600000
[36mkafka        |[0m   offsets.retention.minutes = 10080
[36mkafka        |[0m   offsets.topic.compression.codec = 0
[36mkafka        |[0m   offsets.topic.num.partitions = 50
[36mkafka        |[0m   offsets.topic.replication.factor = 1
[36mkafka        |[0m   offsets.topic.segment.bytes = 104857600
[36mkafka        |[0m   password.encoder.cipher.algorithm = AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding
[36mkafka        |[0m   password.encoder.iterations = 4096
[36mkafka        |[0m   password.encoder.key.length = 128
[36mkafka        |[0m   password.encoder.keyfactory.algorithm = null
[36mkafka        |[0m   password.encoder.old.secret = null
[36mkafka        |[0m   password.encoder.secret = null
[36mkafka        |[0m   port = 9092
[36mkafka        |[0m   principal.builder.class = null
[36mkafka        |[0m   producer.purgatory.purge.interval.requests = 1000
[36mkafka        |[0m   queued.max.request.bytes = -1
[36mkafka        |[0m   queued.max.requests = 500
[36mkafka        |[0m   quota.consumer.default = 9223372036854775807
[36mkafka        |[0m   quota.producer.default = 9223372036854775807
[36mkafka        |[0m   quota.window.num = 11
[36mkafka        |[0m   quota.window.size.seconds = 1
[36mkafka        |[0m   replica.fetch.backoff.ms = 1000
[36mkafka        |[0m   replica.fetch.max.bytes = 1048576
[36mkafka        |[0m   replica.fetch.min.bytes = 1
[36mkafka        |[0m   replica.fetch.response.max.bytes = 10485760
[36mkafka        |[0m   replica.fetch.wait.max.ms = 500
[36mkafka        |[0m   replica.high.watermark.checkpoint.interval.ms = 5000
[36mkafka        |[0m   replica.lag.time.max.ms = 10000
[36mkafka        |[0m   replica.selector.class = null
[36mkafka        |[0m   replica.socket.receive.buffer.bytes = 65536
[36mkafka        |[0m   replica.socket.timeout.ms = 30000
[36mkafka        |[0m   replication.quota.window.num = 11
[36mkafka        |[0m   replication.quota.window.size.seconds = 1
[36mkafka        |[0m   request.timeout.ms = 30000
[36mkafka        |[0m   reserved.broker.max.id = 1000
[36mkafka        |[0m   sasl.client.callback.handler.class = null
[36mkafka        |[0m   sasl.enabled.mechanisms = [GSSAPI]
[36mkafka        |[0m   sasl.jaas.config = null
[36mkafka        |[0m   sasl.kerberos.kinit.cmd = /usr/bin/kinit
[36mkafka        |[0m   sasl.kerberos.min.time.before.relogin = 60000
[36mkafka        |[0m   sasl.kerberos.principal.to.local.rules = [DEFAULT]
[36mkafka        |[0m   sasl.kerberos.service.name = null
[36mkafka        |[0m   sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.jitter = 0.05
[36mkafka        |[0m   sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.window.factor = 0.8
[36mkafka        |[0m   sasl.login.callback.handler.class = null
[36mkafka        |[0m   sasl.login.class = null
[36mkafka        |[0m   sasl.login.refresh.buffer.seconds = 300
[36mkafka        |[0m   sasl.login.refresh.min.period.seconds = 60
[36mkafka        |[0m   sasl.login.refresh.window.factor = 0.8
[36mkafka        |[0m   sasl.login.refresh.window.jitter = 0.05
[36mkafka        |[0m   sasl.mechanism.inter.broker.protocol = GSSAPI
[36mkafka        |[0m   sasl.server.callback.handler.class = null
[36mkafka        |[0m   security.inter.broker.protocol = PLAINTEXT
[36mkafka        |[0m   security.providers = null
[36mkafka        |[0m   socket.receive.buffer.bytes = 102400
[36mkafka        |[0m   socket.request.max.bytes = 104857600
[36mkafka        |[0m   socket.send.buffer.bytes = 102400
[36mkafka        |[0m   ssl.cipher.suites = []
[36mkafka        |[0m   ssl.client.auth = none
[36mkafka        |[0m   ssl.enabled.protocols = [TLSv1.2, TLSv1.1, TLSv1]
[36mkafka        |[0m   ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm = https
[36mkafka        |[0m   ssl.key.password = null
[36mkafka        |[0m   ssl.keymanager.algorithm = SunX509
[36mkafka        |[0m   ssl.keystore.location = null
[36mkafka        |[0m   ssl.keystore.password = null
[36mkafka        |[0m   ssl.keystore.type = JKS
[36mkafka        |[0m   ssl.principal.mapping.rules = DEFAULT
[36mkafka        |[0m   ssl.protocol = TLS
[36mkafka        |[0m   ssl.provider = null
[36mkafka        |[0m   ssl.secure.random.implementation = null
[36mkafka        |[0m   ssl.trustmanager.algorithm = PKIX
[36mkafka        |[0m   ssl.truststore.location = null
[36mkafka        |[0m   ssl.truststore.password = null
[36mkafka        |[0m   ssl.truststore.type = JKS
[36mkafka        |[0m   transaction.abort.timed.out.transaction.cleanup.interval.ms = 60000
[36mkafka        |[0m   transaction.max.timeout.ms = 900000
[36mkafka        |[0m   transaction.remove.expired.transaction.cleanup.interval.ms = 3600000
[36mkafka        |[0m   transaction.state.log.load.buffer.size = 5242880
[36mkafka        |[0m   transaction.state.log.min.isr = 1
[36mkafka        |[0m   transaction.state.log.num.partitions = 50
[36mkafka        |[0m   transaction.state.log.replication.factor = 1
[36mkafka        |[0m   transaction.state.log.segment.bytes = 104857600
[36mkafka        |[0m   transactional.id.expiration.ms = 604800000
[36mkafka        |[0m   unclean.leader.election.enable = false
[36mkafka        |[0m   zookeeper.connect = zookeeper:2181
[36mkafka        |[0m   zookeeper.connection.timeout.ms = 6000
[36mkafka        |[0m   zookeeper.max.in.flight.requests = 10
[36mkafka        |[0m   zookeeper.session.timeout.ms = 6000
[36mkafka        |[0m   zookeeper.set.acl = false
[36mkafka        |[0m   zookeeper.sync.time.ms = 2000
[36mkafka        |[0m  (kafka.server.KafkaConfig)
[36mkafka        |[0m [2020-02-04 12:04:03,415] INFO [ThrottledChannelReaper-Fetch]: Starting (kafka.server.ClientQuotaManager$ThrottledChannelReaper)
[36mkafka        |[0m [2020-02-04 12:04:03,416] INFO [ThrottledChannelReaper-Produce]: Starting (kafka.server.ClientQuotaManager$ThrottledChannelReaper)
[36mkafka        |[0m [2020-02-04 12:04:03,417] INFO [ThrottledChannelReaper-Request]: Starting (kafka.server.ClientQuotaManager$ThrottledChannelReaper)
[36mkafka        |[0m [2020-02-04 12:04:03,440] INFO Log directory /kafka/kafka-logs-acff9186a4ad not found, creating it. (kafka.log.LogManager)
[36mkafka        |[0m [2020-02-04 12:04:03,448] INFO Loading logs. (kafka.log.LogManager)
[36mkafka        |[0m [2020-02-04 12:04:03,455] INFO Logs loading complete in 7 ms. (kafka.log.LogManager)
[36mkafka        |[0m [2020-02-04 12:04:03,469] INFO Starting log cleanup with a period of 5000 ms. (kafka.log.LogManager)
[36mkafka        |[0m [2020-02-04 12:04:03,477] INFO Starting log flusher with a default period of 9223372036854775807 ms. (kafka.log.LogManager)
[36mkafka        |[0m [2020-02-04 12:04:03,945] INFO Awaiting socket connections on kafka:19091. (kafka.network.Acceptor)
[36mkafka        |[0m [2020-02-04 12:04:03,979] INFO [SocketServer brokerId=1001] Created data-plane acceptor and processors for endpoint : EndPoint(kafka,19091,ListenerName(LISTENER_DOCKER_INTERNAL),PLAINTEXT) (kafka.network.SocketServer)
[36mkafka        |[0m [2020-02-04 12:04:03,983] ERROR [KafkaServer id=1001] Fatal error during KafkaServer startup. Prepare to shutdown (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
[36mkafka        |[0m org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Socket server failed to bind to 156.17.42.120:9092: Address not available.
[36mkafka        |[0m   at kafka.network.Acceptor.openServerSocket(SocketServer.scala:632)
[36mkafka        |[0m   at kafka.network.Acceptor.<init>(SocketServer.scala:508)
[36mkafka        |[0m   at kafka.network.SocketServer.createAcceptor(SocketServer.scala:271)
[36mkafka        |[0m   at kafka.network.SocketServer.$anonfun$createDataPlaneAcceptorsAndProcessors$1(SocketServer.scala:240)
[36mkafka        |[0m   at kafka.network.SocketServer.$anonfun$createDataPlaneAcceptorsAndProcessors$1$adapted(SocketServer.scala:238)
[36mkafka        |[0m   at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:62)
[36mkafka        |[0m   at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach$(ResizableArray.scala:55)
[36mkafka        |[0m   at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:49)
[36mkafka        |[0m   at kafka.network.SocketServer.createDataPlaneAcceptorsAndProcessors(SocketServer.scala:238)
[36mkafka        |[0m   at kafka.network.SocketServer.startup(SocketServer.scala:121)
[36mkafka        |[0m   at kafka.server.KafkaServer.startup(KafkaServer.scala:263)
[36mkafka        |[0m   at kafka.server.KafkaServerStartable.startup(KafkaServerStartable.scala:44)
[36mkafka        |[0m   at kafka.Kafka$.main(Kafka.scala:84)
[36mkafka        |[0m   at kafka.Kafka.main(Kafka.scala)
[36mkafka        |[0m Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address not available
[36mkafka        |[0m   at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
[36mkafka        |[0m   at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:433)
[36mkafka        |[0m   at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:425)
[36mkafka        |[0m   at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:223)
[36mkafka        |[0m   at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74)
[36mkafka        |[0m   at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:67)
[36mkafka        |[0m   at kafka.network.Acceptor.openServerSocket(SocketServer.scala:628)
[36mkafka        |[0m   ... 13 more
[36mkafka        |[0m [2020-02-04 12:04:03,986] INFO [KafkaServer id=1001] shutting down (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
[36mkafka        |[0m [2020-02-04 12:04:03,987] INFO [SocketServer brokerId=1001] Stopping socket server request processors (kafka.network.SocketServer)
[36mkafka        |[0m [2020-02-04 12:04:03,993] INFO [SocketServer brokerId=1001] Stopped socket server request processors (kafka.network.SocketServer)
[36mkafka        |[0m [2020-02-04 12:04:03,996] INFO Shutting down. (kafka.log.LogManager)
[36mkafka        |[0m [2020-02-04 12:04:04,028] INFO Shutdown complete. (kafka.log.LogManager)
[36mkafka        |[0m [2020-02-04 12:04:04,029] INFO [ZooKeeperClient Kafka server] Closing. (kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClient)
[36mkafka        |[0m [2020-02-04 12:04:04,146] INFO Session: 0x1001e9c10d90000 closed (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[36mkafka        |[0m [2020-02-04 12:04:04,146] INFO EventThread shut down for session: 0x1001e9c10d90000 (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
[36mkafka        |[0m [2020-02-04 12:04:04,148] INFO [ZooKeeperClient Kafka server] Closed. (kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClient)
[36mkafka        |[0m [2020-02-04 12:04:04,148] INFO [ThrottledChannelReaper-Fetch]: Shutting down (kafka.server.ClientQuotaManager$ThrottledChannelReaper)
[36mkafka        |[0m [2020-02-04 12:04:04,416] INFO [ThrottledChannelReaper-Fetch]: Stopped (kafka.server.ClientQuotaManager$ThrottledChannelReaper)
[36mkafka        |[0m [2020-02-04 12:04:04,416] INFO [ThrottledChannelReaper-Fetch]: Shutdown completed (kafka.server.ClientQuotaManager$ThrottledChannelReaper)
[36mkafka        |[0m [2020-02-04 12:04:04,416] INFO [ThrottledChannelReaper-Produce]: Shutting down (kafka.server.ClientQuotaManager$ThrottledChannelReaper)
[36mkafka        |[0m [2020-02-04 12:04:04,416] INFO [ThrottledChannelReaper-Produce]: Stopped (kafka.server.ClientQuotaManager$ThrottledChannelReaper)
[36mkafka        |[0m [2020-02-04 12:04:04,416] INFO [ThrottledChannelReaper-Produce]: Shutdown completed (kafka.server.ClientQuotaManager$ThrottledChannelReaper)
[36mkafka        |[0m [2020-02-04 12:04:04,416] INFO [ThrottledChannelReaper-Request]: Shutting down (kafka.server.ClientQuotaManager$ThrottledChannelReaper)
[36mkafka        |[0m [2020-02-04 12:04:04,417] INFO [ThrottledChannelReaper-Request]: Stopped (kafka.server.ClientQuotaManager$ThrottledChannelReaper)
[36mkafka        |[0m [2020-02-04 12:04:04,417] INFO [ThrottledChannelReaper-Request]: Shutdown completed (kafka.server.ClientQuotaManager$ThrottledChannelReaper)
[36mkafka        |[0m [2020-02-04 12:04:04,418] INFO [SocketServer brokerId=1001] Shutting down socket server (kafka.network.SocketServer)
[36mkafka        |[0m [2020-02-04 12:04:04,457] INFO [SocketServer brokerId=1001] Shutdown completed (kafka.network.SocketServer)
[36mkafka        |[0m [2020-02-04 12:04:04,463] INFO [KafkaServer id=1001] shut down completed (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
[36mkafka        |[0m [2020-02-04 12:04:04,464] ERROR Exiting Kafka. (kafka.server.KafkaServerStartable)
[36mkafka        |[0m [2020-02-04 12:04:04,471] INFO [KafkaServer id=1001] shutting down (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
```

Comment: I don't understand how you expect people to help you out without even providing the error trace.

Comment: Here is the docker-compose log;

https://textuploader.com/16j2p

Comment: Edit your question and paste the logs there (don't use screenshots or external links).

Comment: Body is limited to 30000 characters; you entered 54275.

Comment: Do you really need to use external IP addresses? And please don't mount your docker socket as a volume (it's a security hole) And why do the comments have `confluentinc/cp-kafka`, but that is not the image you are using

Comment: Note: If you use Minikube instead of Compose, you can use the Confluent Helm charts, which add Prometheus exporters to the containers. https://github.com/confluentinc/cp-helm-charts/